# How to delete single instance of recurring event on Android platform?

Tags: android, instance, recurring

How to delete one single event from a recurring event?

I tried to use exdate using this format  'dtstart' is a start day of a instance I want to delete:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    c.setTimeInMillis(dtstart);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'");
String str = sdf.format(c.getTime());

ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "edited");
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXDATE, str);

    Uri eventUri = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
    int numRow = getApplicationContext()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .update(eventUri, event, CalendarContract.Events._ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(event_id) });
```

and I tried to split a recurring event into two recurring events,
but it sometimes crashed.

Does anybody know how handle this problem?

Comment: This used to be supported by the Android Calendar stock app. But it's not supported anymore. What happened?